# Realm access from incorrect thread

Tags: android, realm

Realm access from incorrect thread

Model:

```
public class RealmModel {

   // private Realm realm;
    private GetObservable getDataRetrofit;
    Realm backgroundRealm ;
    public RealmModel(GetObservable getDataRetrofit) {
        //realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        this.getDataRetrofit = getDataRetrofit;
        backgroundRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public void addListPhoto(final ListApi photoList) {

        backgroundRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {

            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                realm.delete(ListApi.class);
                realm.insertOrUpdate(photoList);
            }
        });
    }


    public void getRealm() {

        backgroundRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                ListApi listApi = realm.where(ListApi.class).findFirst();
                Flowable<ListApi> flowable = null;
                if (listApi != null && listApi.isValid()) {
                    //flowable=Flowable.just(listApi);
                    flowable = listApi.asFlowable();
                }
                getDataRetrofit.getBody(flowable, false);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
@InjectViewState
public class MainPresenter extends MvpPresenter<GetBodyView> implements GetObservable {
    private InternetModel internetModel;
    private RealmModel realmModel;

    public MainPresenter() {
        internetModel = new InternetModel(this);
        realmModel = new RealmModel(this);
        internetModel.retrofitCall();
    }

    @Override
    public void getBody(Flowable<ListApi> observable, final boolean check) {
        if (observable == null) {
            getViewState().fail();
            Log.d("api","fail");
        } else {
            observable
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<ListApi>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(ListApi listApi) {
                            Log.d("api","onNext");
                            if (check) {
                                realmModel.addListPhoto(listApi);
                                getViewState().showRetrofit(listApi.getList());
                            } else {
                                getViewState().showRetrofit(listApi.getList());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            realmModel.getRealm();
                            Log.d("error",t.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Крашится при считывании данных с БД(Realm)

```
Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

Не понимаю уже как сделать так,чтобы оно не крашилось)

Comment: Ну русским же по белому пишут - Realm objects можно трогать только из того потока, в котором его создали...

Comment: @Akina я это понимаю)Но я не понимаю где у меня разные потоки?Я же вроде бы делаю всё в одном реалме,его не закрываю.
Подскажите как мне переделать мой код,чтобы он работал

Comment: RX создает параллельный поток

Comment: @pavlofff так как сделать один поток?

Comment: у меня нет опыта использования RX в связке с Realm, но в инете полно гайдов, как два этих инструмента должны взаимодействовать, чтобы получить нужный результат. В том числе и на офф.сайте Realm

Comment: @pavlofff неужели вы думаете я написал этот вопрос не посмотрев всё об этой проблеме в интернете?Я убил сутки

Answer (score 0):

предполагаю, что в этих строчках:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

вы просите достать объект в потоке Schedulers.io() и передать его в AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Сделайте один поток, на сколько я понял, вам нужен AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Comment: .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
вот так сделать?

Comment: так не работает

Comment: а если убрать вовсе эти две строчки? выполните этот кусок кода в дебаге и посмотрите в каком потоке какая строчка кода выполняется. точки останова должны быть до вызова getBody() и внутри onNext(). и прикрепите весь стек трэйс ошибки из консоли.